# Turning a flashlight on/off via SetActive

Tags: unity, c#, sprites

I don't know if this matters, but I'm using Unity 2D. The code only turns the flashlight off, but not back on.

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class flashlightonoff : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool flashlightisoff = false;

    public GameObject Flashlight;
 
    void Start()
    {
        Flashlight.SetActive(true);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            if (flashlightisoff)
            {
                ON();
            }
            else
            {
                OFF();
            }
        }
        
    }

    void ON()
    {
        Flashlight.SetActive(true);
        flashlightisoff = false;
    }

    void OFF()
    {
        Flashlight.SetActive(false);
        flashlightisoff = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this script on the same object that it's turning off, or in one of its children?

Comment: Same object that its turning off

Comment: And you expect the Update method to still be called on the script, even while its GameObject is inactive? [What do the docs have to say about that](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html)?

Comment: Ok i dont fully understand but i just set it too the flashlight light instead of the actual flashlight and that works. Thanks!

Comment: Want to post your solution as an Answer below?